# How to grant full access to just one Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have created an IAM user in my AWS account for someone to assist me in a project.

How do I grant full access for this user to one specified Lambda function?

By full access, I mean he has the same rights as me (root account) regarding this one function, and not do other things like creating new functions or viewing other functions.

Answer (score 2):

First, be careful what you mean by "full access". This would include the ability to **delete the function**, which is probably not something you'd like to allow.

Take a look at: [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for AWS Lambda - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awslambda.html)

It lists all Lambda-related actions. You'll notice that many of the entries have `function` listed in the **Resource Types** column. This means you can limit the permission being granted to only the stated function(s). So, you'll probably want to limit permission **only to those actions that can be restricted by function**.

The result would be a policy similar to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:function:my-function"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I created an inline policy using the Policy Generator and selecting AWS Lambda service, all actions and selecting the ARN for my Lambda function. The resulting policy is similar to yours above, but with an additional `Sid` property and of course `lambda:*` for `Action`. But the user still hit no `lambda:GetAccountSettings` upon entry to the Lambda page.

Comment: If I attach the built-in AWSLambdaFullAccess policy, the user can access my Lambda function, but also all other functions.

Comment: Oh, you want the user to also be able to use the Lambda management console? That might be tricky. They won't be able to navigate to the function due to the limited permissions, but they should be able to jump directly to that function if you give them the URL to access it. There will probably be random error message appearing, but hopefully they won't matter.